# React native modal open modal from different component using visible prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-modal

How could i open Modal from different component file using my visible prop that is passed inside isVisible with some state and button. Right now the modal is not opening. I am using react-native-modal (https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal)

```
 type ModalProps = {
        visible: boolean;
    };

export function Modal({ visible }: ModalProps) {
    return (
        <ReactNativeModal isVisible={visible} >
                <Pressable>
                    <Icon size={14} name="icon1" />
                </Pressable>
        </ReactNativeModal>
    );
}
```

Calling component in different file

```
 const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);

    function handleModalClose() {
        setModalVisible(false);
    }

    function handleModalOpen() {
        setModalVisible(true);
    }

<Button title="Modal one" onPress={handleModalOpen}>
 <Modal visible={isModalVisible}></Modal>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `isModalVisible` as `visible` prop to the `Modal` component:

```
<Modal visible={isModalVisible}></Modal>
```

If you need to close the modal from the `Modal` component, you can pass also the `setModalVisible` function:

```
type ModalProps = {
    visible: boolean;
    setModalVisible: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};

export function Modal({ visible, setModalVisible }: ModalProps) {
    const handleClose = () => {
        setModalVisible(false);
    }

    ...
```

Comment: This works! What if i have multiple different modals? With this method i think i would be able to open only one type of modal?

Comment: With multiple modals you should probably think about defining a global context provider with the Context API providing the visibility flags and the methods to toggle them